# SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal (I am trying to connect Django with PostgreSQL)

Tags: django, database, postgresql

I am trying to connect Django to the PostgreSQL database, but this is my first time doing it, so I am not sure how exactly to do it. The problem seems to be with the line, where the password is.

[image]

settings.py -

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '<db_name>',
        'USER': '<db_username>',
        'PASSWORD: '<password>',
        'HOST': 'db_hostname_or_ip>',
        'PORT': 'db_port',
    }
}
```

When I try to make migrations in my prompt, (python manage.py makemigrations) I am getting the error mentioned in the title. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: You are missing a quotation mark in  ```"PASSSWORD```. Replace it with ```"PASSWORD"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': '<db_name>',
    'USER': '<db_username>',
    'PASSWORD: '<password>',
    'HOST': 'db_hostname_or_ip>',
    'PORT': 'db_port',
}
```

}

What it actually should be

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': '<db_name>',
    'USER': '<db_username>',
    'PASSWORD': '<password>',
    'HOST': 'db_hostname_or_ip>',
    'PORT': 'db_port',
}
```

}

Actually you're forgetting the closing qoute after PASSWORD